# Can I use any variable 0v-5v source to engage ebike controller to work as if it had a twist style hall throttle?

Tags: circuit-analysis, power-electronics, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, brushed-dc-motor

The hall throttle plugs to a 3 wire connector. 5v, signal and ground coming from the controller goes through the hall throttle and is reduced to 0v-4.2v for a variable speed control. My question is, can I use any source of 0v-5v power to work as a throttle? I'm planning on using the throttle position sensor (0v-5v) from a vehicle to power the throttle on an ebike controller.

Comment: Sounds like it should work. However we can’t give a concise answer as we have no idea of what e-bike controller or throttle sensor you’re referring to. The devil is in the details.

Comment: All e-bike controllers I've seen before used 4.3V power for display and throttle. Yours, of course, can be different, but that may explain 4.2V you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help! My controller is the Yaegoo 350w 48v control. The TPS is a potentiometer. The signal voltages are nearly identical for needed input to available output. I was just wondering if voltage is voltage is voltage basically. I'm presuming that any source between 0.1v and 4.3ish will register as throttle signal going back in to the controller. The way is works is the controller sends a 5v a signal and a ground. The real throttle uses a hall for variable voltage back down the signal wire to tell the controller to send power to the motor.

Comment: Please add the new information into your question rather than bury it in the comments. Tip: 'V' for volt, 'W' for watt, etc.

Comment: I didn't add any new information. I understand the difference in volts and watts, that has nothing to do with my question.